# Flutter - How to prioritize child's gestures detection over parent's scroll gestures?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, gesturedetector

I'm building a cross platform Flutter app (Web, iOS, Android) in which the main feed is a horizontal `PageView`.

Navigation on this pageview is only possible by pan gestures.

Some of the children of this PageView need to be able to receive horizontal gestures => the problem is that FLutter gives priority to the PageView's scroll instead of the child's pan gestures.

---

Here is a sample that reproduces my issue (touchscreen needed) : In the following, you cannot change the width of the nested black54 container with a horizontal gesture.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double containerWidth = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: PageView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Container(height: 500, width: 600, color: Colors.green),
            Container(
              height: 500,
              width: 600,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Center(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        setState(() {
                          containerWidth += details.delta.dx;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          width: containerWidth,
                          height: 50,
                          color: Colors.black54))),
            ),
            Container(height: 500, width: 600, color: Colors.red),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I tried :

- I tried nesting the view inside a gesturedetector with `onHorizontalDragUpdate: (e) {},`
  => it prevents the child from receiving gestures.
- I tried adding
  `behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild` or `HitTestBehavior.translucent`
  => Still nothing.
- The only working method is to disable scrolling physics when the PageController arrives on the second page. But this is not exactly what I want as I still want the user to be able to scroll on the zone around the child gesturedetector.